# How to possibly rephrase a question I see as off-topic

Tags: discussion

Original:

> [I hate seeing my work in real life, what should I do?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/152564/i-hate-seeing-my-work-in-real-life-what-should-i-do)

> I usually like the results of my work, but I hate it when I see it in real life. Not because it looks different, I just don't like that it exists. Recently I designed a logo and it got published online, and I feel bad for hating it. Do you feel the same? How to deal with it?

First, let me plainly state... I empathize with the sentiment of the question. I'm not tying to devalue *any* aspect of the *emotion* behind the posting. I "get it".

Howevever, this to me, is a bad *StackExchange* question. It's not a direct question where direct answers could be provided. As I commented, current answer are all anecdotal and opinon-based. "One time I.... I do this... you should that... I feel your pain.... " Nothing that can be quantified and voted upon. All votes are **emotion based**. "Oh I feel that way.. up vote!" -- Which I understand. This is all *absolutely fine* and I don't inherently disagree with *any* of it.... **IF** SE were a discussion forum, but it's not.

Top this off with hitting Hot Network Questions and yes, it brings in new users and balloons the "view" stat. But you also get a lot of non-designers answering - thinking this type of emotion-driven posting is okay at this stack. Actually, I doubt they care about GD.SE at all, and merely want to throw their emotions on top of the existing emotions. Just human nature. It's *all* merely **emotion based**.. and this is why I think it's "unanswerable". The user is seeking empathy and compassion, not a direct resolution to a problem.

I'll post again.. I *absolutely understand* the emotion and the reasoning. I'm **not** trying to be derogatory towards **any** user, questioner OR answerer. I DO "get it". I'm merely thinking "business" and what SE guidelines are.

So how could such a question be posed where *I think* it would be more inline with SE guidelines - meaning more direct with possibly quantifiable answers...

<sub>(Realize this is written in my voice, not the original user's - which is why I'm hesitant to edit the question itself.)</sub>

---

> I hate seeing my work in real life, what should I do?

> I usually like the results of my work, but I hate it when I see it in real life. Not because it looks different, I just don't like the decisions I made while designing. I don't understand why I'm happy with the work initially, then find so much fault with it later. Is there a way to avoid this dissatisfaction in the future?

> Recently I designed a logo and it got published online. Upon reviewing it, I believe the color I chose may be inappropriate for the client's *actual* usage. When reduced, it doesn't retain some of the aspects I thought were more engaging. I believe I could have ultimately done a better job. However, I can't express *my dissatisfaction* to a *satisfied* client.

> How can I ensure the work I create will be more resilient and hold up better in the long run? Ultimately, I'd like to be happy with my work whenever I see it. Are there methods for ensuring I don't make poor design decisions today, that will be glaring to me tomorrow?

---

Now, this still kind of skirts the "subjective" area. But, I feel there's enough "meat" to it to allow actual *quantifiable* answers, citing the psychology involved, and some methodology to be more consistent.

So.. Am I merely being a bit too adamant about the SE format regarding the original question?

---

As always, please realize I'm not "up in arms" about this at all. I see it as merely a discussion and I'm expressing my opinion and trying to explain my reasoning. Sometimes *how* I write, the words/phrasings I chose, can be read as waaaaay more aggressive than I intend. I'm not seeking to "beat others into submission". If I'm wrong, I'm wrong. `:)`

Comment: I tend to agree that this question might not belong on GDSE. Not so much because it's opinion/emotion based, but more because it's a general issue that applies to many jobs. I also agree with @joojaa though that it would be nice for the site to have more non-Adobe support questions. Ideally the chat could be a place for such discussions, but it's not exactly well-attended. Your attempt at rephrasing the question misses the point as I understand it. The OP doesn't seem to dislike the design itself, but the emotions they get seeing it in real life.

Comment: I'm all for non-Adobe questions. I don't disagree there, but if you last sentence is the case (which I perceive as well), designers just aren't adequately equipped to help others through emotional issues. And again, why I think it's off topic.

Comment: You are probably right. But what makes me hesitate is that this emotional issue isn't just the OP's unique personal experience. It's a more general issue for designers. Something I've often heard from other designers and also experienced myself. But yes, for designers to help with this is a bit like having a mechanic help other mechanics with back pains perhaps. I'm not sure.

Comment: "for designers to help with this is a bit like having a mechanic help other mechanics with back pains perhaps. " --- ermm yup `:)` It's "human condition" related and would probably get better answers at psychology.stackxchange.com `:)`

Comment: While i agree psychology would be a good place. I think there should be room for work psychology that specifically affects designers.

Comment: Could we ask everyone to weigh in on this discussion through an answer, so we can vote and come to a consensus?

Comment: I'd post an answer.. but.. errr. It'd be a copy paste of the question `:)`